# Random unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock Failed

Tags: unix, nginx, php

I am checking my error.log and found a few failed

```
connect() to unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock failed
```

Permissions are fine afaik.

What gives?

owned by nginx:nginx
permissions 660
running nginx obviously.

www.conf

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

default.conf (nginx)

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Running PHP 5.5.14

Comment: What are the permissions? Who owns the socket? How are you trying to connect to the socket? Which web server are you using? What do your configurations look like? We need more information to help.

Comment: edited original post

Comment: Can you update your question with how you are connecting to the socket, IE: Nginx Configuration? Also which version of PHP are you currently running?

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.5.12 FPM Socket permissions were changed to resolve a security related bug, you can read more about that here -> https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060

Your `listen.mode = 0660` should now be set to `listen.mode = 0666`

As for Nginx here is a working example I am currently using:

```
# PHP-FPM Support
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm/nginx.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

I was hoping you would have given a lot more configuration details as requested. The lack thereof is making this more difficult than it needs to be by trying to guess at your situation / configuration setup.

Make sure inside of your FPM Pool Configuration that the following settings are defined:

```
[nginx]
listen = /usr/local/etc/php-fpm/nginx.sock
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
```

You'll notice my listen paths are using `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm` but you can replace those with your own path of choice.

I see you are currently using `/tmp` and although there is not a major problem using that, I'd advise against it and create a dedicated directory for holding your FPM Sockets.

I checked the permissions on my `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm` directory and they are default as `755` and owned by `root:root` at the moment.

Give this a try, I'm sure it will work unless you have something else random happening that isn't obvious with the current information you've given.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem is that it works most of the time with the current configuration, it fails 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Please post your FPM configuration.

Comment: Including your fpm pool configuration for this domain.